# Creating Excel Pivot Tables in Python

Tags: python, excel, pivot-table

Can excel Pivot tables be created by python? Currently I am able to query database table from python and paste it into excel in the form of a normal table. However want to create a Pivot table from python itself so that entire process can be automated.

Comment: Please try to title and tag your questions better. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what else do i need to add that? what is making this confusing?

Comment: Well, I think that the original title (the one I edited) implied that the question was about how to create pivot tables in Python, whereas your question is actually about how to create *Excel* pivot tables in Python, which is not the same thing at all. Now a guess: the reason that no one is answering further is that it presently cannot be done. Good luck to you, and all the best.

Comment: Ok.. :(... i found below code few days ago...but haven't tried it yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532019/creating-pivot-table-in-excel-using-python

Comment: BTW, if you find an answer, you can answer your own question. It might help others who run into this problem. Again, good luck to you.

Comment: Actually I wanted to edit this latest reply.. but you answered before that :)..i appreciate your quick response... i haven't tried this code yet as i need to get few libraries installed... do you think that it will work what i am looking for..

Comment: The Excel pivot table format is not well documented. The Python Excel manipulation module openpyxl mentions that it can not create a pivot table, altho' it can read an already existing one. I have found Excel automation (external control of the Excel application using Windows specific APIs) very unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a MS Windows environment you can control the actual Excel application using the pywin32, check on [this article](https://pbpython.com/windows-com.html) by Chris Moffitt

Here an initial idea on how to solve it.
Create an excel with the data in one sheet and the pivot table in other. Then open and update the data

here some pseudocode:
import win32com.client as win32

```
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
# here update the data
excel.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
excel.Application.quit()
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same question and indeed, you can use python to create Excel objects such as pivot tables and charts.

Since copying all the code here seems quite a stretch, I included a good link that explains how to initiate an Excel object (read Pivot Table), fill it with your data and place it in an Excel sheet.

The functions provided in the code example are almost plug and play.

Check this link:
https://trenton3983.github.io/files/solutions/2020-06-22_pivot_table_win32com/create_pivot_table_with_win32com.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [Read how to write good answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30132821)

Comment: thx added a liitle more context