# Create Pivot Table Slicer in Excel using Python (WIN32com)

Tags: python, excel, pivot-table, win32com, slicers

I've created a Pivot table in excel using the code from the top answer here:
[Creating pivot table in Excel using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532019/creating-pivot-table-in-excel-using-python)

I am looking to create a Slicer for the pivot table, however all attempts have resulted in the same error. 
It looks like SlicerCaches needs to be created followed by adding the pivot table. Below is the code I've tried:

```
#SlicerSourceRange = Sheet2.Range("A:B")
#SlicerSourceRange.Select()

pvts = wb.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Field").PivotTableName
```

I've tried different variations including with or without selecting the range, using PivotTable Name or Source data etc but no luck. Here is the error I'm getting:

> File
>   "D:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.7\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9\SlicerCaches.py",
>   line 77, in **call**
>       ret = self.*oleobj*.InvokeTypes(0, LCID, 2, (9, 0), ((12, 1),),Index pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.',
>   (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147024809), None)

Any help with this would be much appreciated!