# Creating a Functional Pivot Table With Python

Tags: python, excel, functional-programming, pivot

I have not been able to find a definitive yes or no answer to this, but I am just wondering if there is a way to create a functional pivot table in Excel with python? I am able to pivot data with pandas, and save the data itself to a sheet or file, but I was hoping to create one with drop down options within excel after saving it.

Thank you.

Comment: Here's a post explaining how but it is not for the faint of heart: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532019/creating-pivot-table-in-excel-using-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating pivot table in Excel using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532019/creating-pivot-table-in-excel-using-python)

Comment: @katardin unfortunately no :/ I came across this myself and tried the code in the answer and it did make the data.. but no pivot table. I appreciate your response though, and I hope there is an easier solution, you weren't kidding that was hard to read through.